# Computed macro names

Tags: nmake

The GNU Make program proves the feature of  [computed names](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Computed-Names.html). I have to use Microsoft nmake program and need to check if either a macro has a specified value or is at least defined.

The makefile defines a macro `FOO` with the value `DEVICE`. Further it can be that the macro `PLAT_DEVICE` is defined with the value `1`. In GNU make syntax you could use

```
FOO=DEVICE
PLAT_DEVICE=1

!if "$(PLAT_$(FOO))" == "1"
!message I am here.
!endif
```

The value of the macro `FOO` defines what other macro is checked here. Unfortunately nmake doesn't understand this. The condition evaluates always to false, the message is never shown.

How can I implement this with nmake?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** This is my first answer, and is not that useful. See my second answer on using environment variables.

---

Unfortunately, NMAKE does not have Computed Variable Names as in GNU Make.

But it *does* allow the construction of macro names from other macros: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/defining-an-nmake-macro?view=vs-2017.

So the following work-around may work, depending on your situation:

```
DEVICE = 1
PLAT_DEVICE_$(DEVICE) =

!ifdef PLAT_DEVICE_1
!message I am here.
!endif
```

Or, as minor variation of this idea:

```
DEVICE = 1
PLAT_DEVICE_$(DEVICE) = plat_device

!if "plat_device" == "$(PLAT_DEVICE_1)"
!message I am here.
!endif
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** you can use *environment variables* instead of make macros to compute the names,  For example, this makefile:

```
FOO=DEVICE
PLAT_DEVICE=1

!if [set PLAT_DEVICE=$(PLAT_DEVICE)] # add macro to environment
!endif

!if [cmd /c if "%PLAT_$(FOO)%"=="1" exit 1] # do test
!message I am here.
!endif
```

will give:

```
>nmake -l
I am here.
```

Or this variant,

```
FOO=DEVICE
PLAT_DEVICE=42

!if [set FOO=$(FOO)] && \
    [set PLAT_DEVICE=$(PLAT_DEVICE)]
!endif

!if [cmd /c if "%PLAT_$(FOO)%"=="42" exit 1]
!message Test 1a: I am here.
!endif

!if [cmd /c if "%PLAT_%FOO%%"=="42" exit 1]
!message Test 1b: I am here too.
!endif

all:
    @     echo Test 2a: %%PLAT_$(FOO)%%
    @call echo Test 2b: %%PLAT_%%FOO%%%%
```

will give:

```
>nmake -l
Test 1a: I am here.
Test 1b: I am here too.
Test 2a: 42
Test 2b: 42
```

One major drawback in this answer is that the exporting has to be done explicitly for each make macro. The nmake `-l` switch is a just an abbreviation for `/nologo` (undocumented?).

---

**Longer answer.** The above makefile uses several techniques or tricks. I will try to unravel these in a list of four items.

**Item 1:** First note `nmake`, unlike GNU make, has persistent environment variables (aka *variables* in nmake). For example,

```
all: bar
    @echo Test 3: %%BAR%%

bar:
    @set BAR=Hello World!
```

gives:

```
>nmake -l
Test 3: Hello World!
```

**Item 2:** You can convert macros to variables, or create a variable, in at least two places:

- in a recipe command line, as shown in Item 1, or
- in a command executed during preprocessing, in square brackets `[...]`.

For example,

```
AAA = FOO
BBB = BAR
FOO_BAR = This works!
FOO_BAZ = This also works!

!if [set FOO_BAR=$(FOO_BAR)] && \
    [set FOO_BAZ=$(FOO_BAZ)] && \
    [set CCC=%$(AAA)_$(BBB)%]
!endif

all:
    @echo Test 4: %%$(AAA)_$(BBB)%%
    @echo Test 5: %%CCC%%
```

gives:

```
>nmake -l
Test 4: This works!
Test 5: This works!

>nmake -l BBB=BAZ
Test 4: This also works!
Test 5: This also works!
```

Two odd points about this. First, it seems each variable must be set with its own command. For example,

```
!if [set FOO_BAR=$(FOO_BAR) && set FOO_BAZ=$(FOO_BAZ)]
!endif
```

does not work (I may be missing something obvious here). Second, the `&&` connective is almost irrelevant here: it does not short-circuit in nmake, and we are discarding the the result, so probably anything else like `+` would work just as well.

**Item 3:** Item 2 doesn't really illustrate nesting: the nesting shown is a macro within a variable. But true nesting does work. The makefile:

```
AAA = FOO
BBB = BAR
FOO_BAR = This works!

!if [set AAA=$(AAA)] && \
    [set BBB=$(BBB)] && \
    [set FOO_BAR=$(FOO_BAR)]
!endif

!if [cmd /c if "%%AAA%_%BBB%%"=="This works!" exit 1]
!message Test 6: I am here
!endif

all:
    @call echo Test 7: %%%%AAA%%_%%BBB%%%%
```

will give:

```
>nmake -l
Test 6: I am here
Test 7: This works!
```

In the recipe, the `call` seems to be needed simulate delayed expansion; see [Stephan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/318716) to [Variables are not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected). It is not needed in the Test 6, `=="This works!"` test.

**Item 4:** The preprocessing tests shown in:

```
!if [cmd /c if "%PLAT_$(FOO)%"=="42" exit 1]
!message Test 1a: I am here.
!endif

!if [cmd /c if "%PLAT_%FOO%%"=="42" exit 1]
!message Test 1b: I am here too.
!endif
```

are similar to the Unix `test` command, except here TRUE=1.